# How can I get the distinct values from SQLite

Tags: android, sql, sqlite

I have a problem while getting the distinct values from my table. I created one method which returns the String Array like this:

```
    public String[] getUniversityNames() {
    String[] university = new String[0];
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

    Cursor cursor = db.query(true, TABLE_QUESTIONS,
            new String[] { KEY_UNIVERSITY }, null, null, null, null, null,
            null);

    int i = 0;
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            university[i] = cursor.getString(0); //Error occurs here @ Line 119
            i++;
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    } else {
        Log.w("AQUEST", "No Data Found.");
    }
    cursor.close();
    return university;
}
```

And gives me the following error in logcat:

```
E/AndroidRuntime(11100): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime(11100): java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=0; index=0
E/AndroidRuntime(11100): at     com.anisTronic.quest.database.DatabaseHandler.getUniversityNames(DatabaseHandler.java:119)
```

I have 19 rows in my table.

Please help me out from this. I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your bug probably is:

```
String[] university = new String[0];
```

...

`university` is an array with 0 elements.

then:

```
university[i] = cursor.getString(0); //Error occurs here @ Line 119
```

you try and add an element.  You cannot, since `university` cannot hold an element, hence the exception.   You could return some kind of `Collection` or collect them in a `Collection` before changing it to an array.

Comment: I found my bug from your suggestion. But I tried different approach to solve my problem. What i did is, I first counted the number of rows that cursor returned and then created an String array according. But is it the good practice?

Comment: No, since you must traverse the result set twice (once to count and allocate, and once to extract the `String`s). One solution suggested by @useletters in his answer is to use an `ArrayList<String>` (a `Collection`) to gather up the `String`s.  Then you can extract an array from it (`toArray`) if you want to return a `String[]`.  That would require the least amount of changes to your code.

Comment: Thankyou. I have made it accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

The String Array `university` is empty as per your initialisation `String[] university = new String[0];`

Try using `ArrayList<String>`
http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/ArrayList.html